# jsonlines file data manipulation

Tags: python-3.x

i have below data set:

```
    "network": {
        "networkElementId": "Cluster06_otmsrbs6521",
        "ossPrefix": "SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=ERBS-SUBNW-1,MeContext=Cluster06_otmsrbs6521",
        "platformType": "",
        "ossModelIdentity": "18.Q3-R4J",
        "neType": "MSRBS_V1"
    }
    {
        "networkElementId": "Cluster06_otmsrbs6521",
        "ossPrefix": "SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=ERBS-SUBNW-1,MeContext=Cluster06_otmsrbs6521", "platformType": "",
        "ossModelIdentity": "18.Q3-R4J", "neType": "MSRBS_V1"
    }
}
```

i want to extract "neType": "MSRBS_V1" using regular expressin in python. need your guidance

Comment: why regex when you can parse this like normal JSON?

Comment: https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/